# How to make an AJAX request respond faster on a remote server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I perform CRUD operations with PHP and jQuery AJAX. The speed on my localhost is great, however the problem is when I deploy my application to the remote server. It processes slower than I expected. How can I improve my AJAX request to be executed faster?

```js
(function($) {
  create();
  showResult();
})(jQuery)

function create() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: $('#Form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $('.msg').html(data);
      showResult();
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.msg').html();
    }
  })
}

function showResult() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'result.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      $('.result').html(data);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you know where the delay comes from?  Is the server response slower or the actual connection to the server?

Comment: AJAX only goes as fast as your internet connection and the remote server will allow it. There's nothing you can do to optimise the JS. All you can do to improve the performance is optimise the PHP code in `page.php` and `result.php` or pay for a better server hosting plan.

Comment: Also note that your code is using an IIFE, not a document.ready handler. This is fine if you execute the JS just before `</body>` but may cause issues if it's placed in the `<head>`. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: I don't know where the delay is coming, but when I run to my localhost it is very fast, I thought about using beforeSend to load the spin, but I think that will not solve my problem. @NigelRen

Comment: Okey, So what can I do to achieve that? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: As I said, optimise your PHP code. You need to performance test it and find the slow parts and improve them. We can't help with that as you've not shown that code in the question. Profiling the entire request is the first step though. Open the network tab of dev tools when making the request to see how long each step takes.

Comment: Okey, I'm trying what you have recommended me.